# Android MediaPlugin receive null pointer exception base.onCreate(bundle)

Tags: android, xamarin, plugins, xamarin.forms, media

I am using Xamarin MediaPlugin:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

the app normally works fine until now?

I received this exception if I not add the Android-N required setting on the link.

> ClassNotFoundException MediaPluginActivity
>
> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity ---> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac/MediaPickerActivity ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.touchjet.app-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.touchjet.app-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.touchjet.app-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.touchjet.app-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>     at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
>     at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>     at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>     at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac/MediaPickerActivity
>     at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
>     at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>     at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>     at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.touchjet.app-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.touchjet.app-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>     at ... 13 more
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00082] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12649
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:562
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:568
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:573
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.Type type) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:513
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
>     at TouchjetApp.DeviceSharingPage+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00088] in /Users/simonlam/Desktop/Touchjet Application Repository/App/TouchjetApp/DeviceSharingPage.xaml.cs:162
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113
>     at TouchjetApp.DeviceSharingPage+<>c__asyncA.MoveNext () [0x000b4] in /Users/simonlam/Desktop/Touchjet Application Repository/App/TouchjetApp/DeviceSharingPage.xaml.cs:120
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018
>     at Android.App.SyncContext+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
>     at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
>     at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81
>     at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:b38f4a8d-8567-4aab-97ff-10ed9804df2d (intptr,intptr)
>     at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity
>     at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
>     at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
>     at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>     at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>     at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     at Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac/MediaPickerActivity
>     at ... 13 more
>     at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5447fdd08b040856919d3dd3a41d94bac.MediaPickerActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.touchjet.app-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.touchjet.app-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>     at ... 13 more

If I add the Android-N section (in androidManifest, and xml/file_paths.xml)

> I will have NullPointerException in base.onCreate(bundle).

APP_PACKAGE_NAME i replaced with

> com.abc.app

OR

> ABC.Droid

but none of them work.

Comment: It is working now but don't know what has changed to make that happened. I removed the Android-N required section.

Comment: where the Android-N section is ?